# how to use macro for a unsigned long number?

Tags: c++, c, macros

Here're my codes:

```
#define MSK 0x0F
#define UNT 1
#define N 3000000000

unsigned char aln[1+N];
unsigned char pileup[1+N];

void set(unsigned long i)
{
    if ((aln[i] & MSK) != MSK ) {
        aln[i] += UNT;
    }
}
int main(void) {}
```

When I try to compile it, the compiler complains like this:

```
 tmp/ccJ4IgSa.o: In function `set':
 bitmacs.c:(.text+0xf): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `aln' defined in COMMON \
 section in /tmp/ccJ4IgSa.o
  bitmacs.c:(.text+0x29): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `aln' defined in COMMON\
 section in /tmp/ccJ4IgSa.o
 bitmacs.c:(.text+0x32): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `aln' defined in COMMON\
  section in /tmp/ccJ4IgSa.o
```

I think the reason may be the `N` is too big, because it can compile successfully if I change N to 2000000000. But I need 3000000000 as the value of N..

Anyone has idea about that?

Comment: Um... that's kinda big for a global array. You sure you don't want to dynamically allocate it with `malloc()` or `new` instead?

Comment: Just to validate your thinking, 3000,000,000 doesn't fit in a signed 32 bit integer, but 2000,000,000 does.

Comment: @Mysticial It would be far too large for the stack, but what problems do you expect with a global?

Comment: @delnan: `relocation truncated to fit`

Comment: @delnan Some compilers/environments impose limits on the size of the binary/global data. Assuming the limit is 4GB, you will overrun it with a pair of 3GB arrays.

Comment: @Mysticial Wait, 6GB? Sure, that's a problem, but it's a problem regardless of how you allocate. A 32 bit process simply doesn't have that much address space, and `malloc` can't change anything about that.

Comment: @delnan It *looks* like the OP is compiling for 64-bit since I see a "X86_64" token. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Mysticial Maybe, but then there shouldn't be such a limit on the size... or not? Whatever, I don't know enough about linkers and loaders to reason any further.

Comment: @delnan I know on Windows, even 64-bit applications have a 4GB limit on both binary and static memory size. It's only the heap that lets you go > 4GB.

Comment: @Mysticial Have all my upvotes... oh well, at least a comment upvote then. And thanks for filling my daily "learnt on SO" quota :)

Comment: @Mystical: can you point to a reference for that information?  I'm not questioning it - I'd just like to read up on any other info the reference might have.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I remember reading somewhere on MSDN that an executable can't be bigger than 4GB. (or something like that) That was at least a year ago. I'll see if I can find that link.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I didn't find the original one, but [here's another link](http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0036/) that says that static data cannot exceed 2GB on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disregarding the "formal" problem that your numeric literal isn't of the correct type (see the other answers for the correct syntax), the key point here is that it's a very bad idea to allocate a 3 GB static/global array.

`static` and global<sup>1</sup> variables on most platforms are mapped directly from the executable image, which means that your executable would have to be as big as 3 GB, which is quite big even for current day standards. Even if on some platforms this limitation may be lifted (see the comments), you don't have any control on how to handle the failure of allocation.

Most importantly, global variables are not intended for such big stuff, and you are likely to find problems with arbitrary limits imposed by the linker (such as the one you found) and the loader. Instead, you should allocate anything that's bigger than a few KBs on the heap, using `malloc`, `new` or some platform-specific function, handling gracefully the possible failure at runtime.

Still, keep in mind that for an application running under almost any 32 bit operating system it's not possible to get 3 GB of contiguous memory as you request, and it's impossible altogether to get more than one of these arrays (=more than 4 GB of contiguous memory) without resorting to platform-specific tricks (e.g. mapping only specific parts of the arrays in memory at a given moment).

Also, are you sure that you do need all that contiguous memory since your program starts to run? Isn't there some better data structure/algorithm that could avoid allocating all that memory?

---

1. In general, what the standard calls variables with *static storage duration*.

Comment: RE executable size: At least some popular platforms have sections which require only a start address and a size, and only during loading they fill that space with data (e.g. all zeros). I think it's called `bss` on Linux. I have no idea if this applicable to OP's code an platform though.

Comment: for a 32-bit executable, the size itself still likely needs to fit into a 32-bit field though

Comment: @Useless Quite possible. But as Mystical is currently arguing in the comments on the question itself, OP may very well be on a 64 bit platform, and I *would* expect executable formats to be adjusted to that.

Answer (score 9):

Per your original question: use the integer literal suffix *UL* (or similar) to force the storage type of N:

```
#define N 3000000000UL
```

However, (per your comment on HLundvall's answer) the `relocation truncated to fit` error obviously isn't due to this - it may (as Mystical and Matt Lacey say) simply be too big to fit in the segment.

---

As an aside, if you ask a seperate question explaining what you're trying to accomplish with your huge arrays, someone may be able to suggest a better solution (that is more likely to fit in memory)

For example:

- your sample code is only using the low nibble of each byte in the code shown: you could pack this into half the size (which is admittedly still much too large)
- depending on your access patterns, you might be able to keep the array on disk and cache a working subset in memory
- there may be better overall algorithms and data structures if we knew what you needed

Answer (score 1):

To enter a numeric constant of type unsigned long use:

```
#define N 3000000000UL
```

Comment: @GManNickG the downvote isn't mine,  it still complains about `relocation truncated`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that gcc (by default) uses pc-relative accesses to get the address of static data objects on x86_64 targets, and those accesses are limited to 2^31 bytes maximum.  So if the symbol ends up getting placed more than 2GB away from the code that accesses it, you'll end up getting this link error when it tries to use an offset that is too big to fit in the 32 bits of space allowed in the instruction.

You can avoid this problem by using the `-mcmodel=large` option to gcc.  This tells it to not assume that it can use 32-bit PC relative offsets to access symbols (among other things)

Note that the type suffix of the constant literal is mostly irrelevant -- a constant literal that is too big for an int will automatically become a long (or even long long if needed) without any suffix.  See 6.4.4.1.5 of the C99 spec.

Answer (score -1):

Your executable is trying to put objects in memory past the 4GB mark, which is not allowed. See this link: http://www.technovelty.org/code/c/relocation-truncated.html.

From the article: "If you're seeing this and you're not hand-coding, you probably want to check out the -mmodel argument to gcc."